# How to update properties of data class show compose ui can observe the changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a CounterScreenUiState data class with a single property called counterVal (integer). If I am updating the value of my counter from viewModel which of the following is the correct approach?

Approach A:

```
data class CounterUiState(
    val counterVal: Int = 0,
)

class CounterViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var uiState by mutableStateOf(CounterUiState())
       private set


    fun inc() {
        uiState = uiState.copy(counterVal = uiState.counterVal + 1)
    }

    fun dec() {
        uiState = uiState.copy(counterVal = uiState.counterVal - 1)
    }
}
```

or

Approach B:

```
data class CounterUiState(
    var counterVal: MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(0)
)

class CounterViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var uiState by mutableStateOf(CounterUiState())
       private set


    fun inc() {
        uiState.counterVal.value = uiState.counterVal.value + 1
    }

    fun dec() {
        uiState.counterVal.value = uiState.counterVal.value - 1
    }
}
```

For the record, I tried both approach and both works well without unnecessary re-compositions.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 4):

> So to summarize, "implementation" and "performance" wise, your'e only
> choice is A.

This is not true. It's a common pattern that is used other Google's sample apps, JetSnack for instance, and default functions like rememberScrollable or Animatable are the ones that come to my mind. And in that article it's also shared as

```
@Stable
class MyStateHolder {
  var isLoading by mutableStateOf(false)
}
```

or

```
@Stable
class ScrollState(initial: Int) : ScrollableState {

/**
 * current scroll position value in pixels
 */
var value: Int by mutableStateOf(initial, structuralEqualityPolicy())
    private set

// rest of the code
}
```

Animatable class

```
class Animatable<T, V : AnimationVector>(
    initialValue: T,
    val typeConverter: TwoWayConverter<T, V>,
    private val visibilityThreshold: T? = null,
    val label: String = "Animatable"
) {

    internal val internalState = AnimationState(
        typeConverter = typeConverter,
        initialValue = initialValue
    )

    /**
     * Current value of the animation.
     */
    val value: T
        get() = internalState.value

 
    /**
     * The target of the current animation. If the animation finishes un-interrupted, it will
     * reach this target value.
     */
    var targetValue: T by mutableStateOf(initialValue)
        private set

}
```

Omitted some code from `Animatable` for simplicity but as can be seen it's a common pattern to use a class that hold one or multiple `MutableState`s. Even type AnimationState hold its own MutableState.

You can create state holder classes and since these are not e not variables but states without them changing you won't have recompositions unless these states change. The thing needs to be changed with option B is instead of using

```
data class CounterUiState(
    var counterVal: MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(0)
)
```

You should change it to

```
class CounterUiState(
    var counterVal by mutableStateOf(0)
)
```

since you don't need to set new instance of State itself but only the value.

And since you already wrap your states inside your uiState there is no need to use

```
 var uiState by mutableStateOf(CounterUiState())
       private set
```

you can have this inside your `ViewModel` as

val uiState = CounterUiState()

or inside your `Composable` after wrapping with `remember`

```
@Composable
fun rememberCounterUiState(): CounterUiState = remember {
    CounterUiState()
}
```

With this pattern you can store `State`s in one class and hold variables that should not trigger recomposition as part of internal calculations and it's up to developer expose these non-state variables based on the design.

https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/home/search/Search.kt

```
@Stable
class SearchState(
    query: TextFieldValue,
    focused: Boolean,
    searching: Boolean,
    categories: List<SearchCategoryCollection>,
    suggestions: List<SearchSuggestionGroup>,
    filters: List<Filter>,
    searchResults: List<Snack>
) {
    var query by mutableStateOf(query)
    var focused by mutableStateOf(focused)
    var searching by mutableStateOf(searching)
    var categories by mutableStateOf(categories)
    var suggestions by mutableStateOf(suggestions)
    var filters by mutableStateOf(filters)
    var searchResults by mutableStateOf(searchResults)
    val searchDisplay: SearchDisplay
        get() = when {
            !focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.Categories
            focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.Suggestions
            searchResults.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.NoResults
            else -> SearchDisplay.Results
        }
}
```

Also for skippibility

> Compose will treat your CounterUiState as unstable and down the road
> it will definitely cause you headaches because what ever you do,

This is misleading. Most of the time optimizing for skippability is premature optimization as mentioned in that article and the one shared by originally Chris Banes.

> Should every Composable be skippable? No.
>
> Chasing complete skippability for every composable in your app is a
> premature optimization. Being skippable actually adds a small overhead
> of its own which may not be worth it, you can even annotate your
> composable to be non-restartable in cases where you determine that
> being restartable is more overhead than it’s worth. There are many
> other situations where being skippable won’t have any real benefit and
> will just lead to hard to maintain code. For example:
>
> A composable that is not recomposed often, or at all.

Comment: Thank you @Doc Thrace for the correction, my understanding of the internals are definitely still quite premature.

Comment: I didn't even read the post but doc, given the length and the apparent detail coupled with your centuries of experience treating the diseased code, I'll up-vote straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're working on a list if you need bidirectional data flow then it's better to keep the list in ViewModel and update as the data changes.

In Viewmodel.Kt

```
//Create a mutable list which will be used inside ViewModel only
private val _listOfProducts = mutableStateListOf<ModelClassProduct>()

//This will be used in ui . just fetch this list and render in lazyList
val listOfProducts: List<ModelClassProduct> = _listOfProducts

// Update the list when you get data from Api or db
private fun updateData(listOfProductsFromDataSoruce: List<ModelClassProduct>) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        _listOfProducts.addAll(listOfItems)
    }
}

//Call this when you want to update any product in the list from anywhere. Creating a copy is important because compose doesn't recompose if the object reference is same. 

fun updateCount(index: Int, cartCount: Int) {
    val product = _listOfProducts[index]
    _listOfProducts[index] = product.copy(cartCount = cartCount)
}
```